# Комбинаторика, как сделать онлайн генератор

Tags: javascript, комбинаторика

Задача. Есть 25 цифр от 1 до 25 (1,2,3,4,5....25) , нужно составить 1000 комбинаций из пяти цифр

```
x-x-x-x-x
x-x-x-x-x
x-x-x-x-x
x-x-x-x-x
```

Исключить повторения (Повторения именно в присутствии данных чисел), например считать повторением:

```
5-15-24-13-11
15-24-13-11-5
```

и так далее.
Если есть код js, с html генерацией таблиц ткните пожалуйста носом, спасибо.

Comment: В пределах одной комбинации значения могут повторяться?

Comment: @Yaant Нет, в пределах одной комбинации значения повторяться не должны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, что-нибудь в этом духе:

```js
function generate() {
  const numbers = (new Array(25)).fill(1).map((a, i) => a + i);
  let resultSet = new Map();
  while (resultSet.size < 1000) {
    let nums = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 5);
    let key = (nums.sort() + '');
    resultSet.set(key, nums);
  }
  resultSet.forEach(val => document.write(val.join('-') + ` ${randInt()}<br>`));
}

function shuffle(arr) {
  return arr.map(el => {
    return {
      item: el,
      sort: Math.random()
    }
  }).sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort).map(el => el.item);
}

function randInt(min = 1, max = 5) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Нажать" onclick="generate()"/>
```

Comment: Отлично, но только в результате не тысяча комбинаций

Comment: и как сделать, чтобы генерация происходила при нажатии кнопки

Comment: Тысяча, просто сниппет тут ограничивает число выводимых строк, похоже.

Comment: спросил про кнопку, так как при добавлении на страницу кода вот сюда https://codepen.io/sochi-russia/pen/WYwMBy  , ничего не происходит

Comment: Ну, Вы же наверно знаете, как сделать, чтобы по нажатию кнопки выполнился какой-нибудь код?

Comment: Честно, не знаю.

Comment: Как же не происходит? Откройте консоль. :)

Comment: Увидел), спасибо, но все же как кнопкой это сделать?

Comment: Отредактировал ответ.

Comment: А если к этим комбинациям добавить число от 1 до 5 в конце (x-x-x-x-x 1  x-x-x-x-x 4 x-x-x-x-x 5), что бы с ними комбинировались? Такое возможно?

Comment: Можно и добавить. Но непонятно, что именно должно в результате получиться.

Comment: x-x-x-x-x 1 x-x-x-x-x 4 x-x-x-x-x 5

Comment: Отредактировал ответ еще раз, хотя это уже довольно далеко ушло от изначального вопроса. :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: извините еще раз, а как эти значения вставить в html таблицу?